# Scala Compilter Interface Error - Build does not generate - IntelliJ

Tags: scala, error-handling, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build a calculator in Scala without using Control Flow elements and I am getting this error, maybe a possible solution?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.CompilerInterface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.getBridgeClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:372)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.bridgeInstance(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:321)
    at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:95)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:57)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.doCompile(LocalServer.scala:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:30)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.compileLogic(Main.scala:207)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.$anonfun$handleCommand$1(Main.scala:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.decorated$1(Main.scala:180)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.handleCommand(Main.scala:187)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.serverLogic(Main.scala:163)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:103)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.sbt` and `project/build.properties` files?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a short step-by-step guide on how to find code in these files?

Comment: So you are not using **sbt** then? How are you creating your project? Just from the IDE?

Comment: I am not sure actually, I started learning SCALA only recently and our professor asked us to clone a repository.

Comment: I've made a public GitHub repository you can clone if that helps:

https://github.com/rudolfsmsp/Cacl_2

The external libraries we use are scala-sdk-2.12.10 and corretto-1.8_322

Comment: Oh so you are using **maven**, when are you getting that error? which command did you execute? Also, what is your JDK?

Comment: About JDK, I am using 17 Oracle OpenJDK version 17.0.1

The error was showing up the 1st time (and is still showing currently) when I cloned the repository and tried building the project.

Comment: Uhm, no idea then, you may try asking your professor for support. You may also try using **Java 11** instead.